# C# async / await unobserved exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I'm trying to understand why the following code:

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrashAsync("aaa");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log($"observed exception");

        Log($"Exception: {exception.Message}");
    }
}

private async Task CrashAsync(string title)
{
    Log($"CrashAsync ({title}) - before");

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    throw new Exception($"CrashAsync ({title})");

    Log($"CrashAsync ({title}) - after");
}
```

produces the expected result:

> thread #1: CrashAsync (aaa) - before
>
> thread #1: observed exception
>
> thread #1: Exception: CrashAsync (aaa)

but if I change it to this one:

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrashAsync("aaa").ContinueWith(async (t) =>
        {                   
            await CrashAsync("bbb");
        },TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log($"observed exception");

        Log($"Exception: {exception.Message}");
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

> thread #1: CrashAsync (aaa) - before
>
> thread #1: observed exception
>
> thread #1: Exception: A task was canceled.
>
> thread #2: unobserved exception
>
> thread #2: System.Exception: CrashAsync (aaa)
>     at AsyncTest.AsyncTestPage+c__async3.MoveNext () [0x000ad] in /Users/johndoe/Development/Xamarin/AsyncTest/AsyncTest/AsyncTestPage.xaml.cs:82

where:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"thread #{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}: unobserved exception");

    foreach (var exception in e.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"thread #{Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}: {exception}");
    }
};
```

The continuation condition is not satisfied so the ContinueWith task is cancelled, but why do I have unobserved exception?

Comment: afaik UnobservedExceptions appear when a exception is thrown in an async void methode that is no top level event handler (just a normal void method marked as async)

Comment: you mean the one passed to ContinueWith?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `ContinueWith` here or is this just an academic exercise?

Comment: @Radinator UnobservedExceptions are thrown when any async method throws an exception which is not handled on the main thread

Comment: @Ant P: working with legacy code. In order to do this, I have to understand behaviour of this async/await + ContinueWith combination.

Comment: @aguyngueran I'd be tempted to go all or nothing on it... unless someone has already mixed them D:

Comment: @Ant P: it is already a mix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You await `Task` returned by `ContinueWith`, so you observe exception related to this `Task` - that it was cancelled (`TaskCanceledException`). But you don't observe original exception thrown by CrashAsync (so "CrashAsync aaa") exception, hence the behavior you observe.

Here is sample code to get more understanding:

```
static async void Test() {
    var originalTask = CrashAsync("aaa");
    var onSuccess = originalTask.ContinueWith(async (t) =>
    {
        await CrashAsync("bbb");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    var onFault = originalTask.ContinueWith(t => {                    
        Log("Observed original exception: " + t.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

So in short - just await your task and catch exception if any. You don't need to use `ContinueWith` at all, because if you use await - the rest of the method is *already* a continuation.

Comment: Does it mean I shouldn't be using ContinueWith that excludes faulted states if I'm not 100% sure the continued task runs to completion?

Comment: @aguyngueran: You shouldn't be using `ContinueWith` *at all*. Just use `await`.

Comment: I've added some code to help you understand the problem.

Comment: I understand that in this sample scenario having two lines of code: "await CrashAsync("aa"); await CrashAsync("bbb");" would produce the same flow (with proper error handling) but the above is just an example. I'm working on some legacy code that has quite a few ContinueWith calls.

Comment: Well await togethet with ContinueWith - _thats_ what is messy :) Dont do that. Code is just to make more clear why you observe what you observe - not to be used.

Comment: @Evk: Not at all. `ContinueWith` has inappropriate defaults for asynchronous code, such as defaulting to the current task scheduler and allowing child continuations. Rewriting the code to use `await` will make it cleaner, easier to understand, and **more correct** in its handling of edge cases.

Comment: @StephenCleary I think that is what I mean already: don't use ContinueWith at all, but even if you should for some reason, at least don't mix it with async\await. Not that I advocate to using ContinueWith _instead_ of async\await. Code that I provided is for OP to better understand what's going on in his case, not to actually _use_ it.